# Using findMenuCommandId('string with accent') on After Effects french version doestn't work

Tags: jsx, after-effects

I have an issue using After Effects extendscript function `app.findMenuCommandId()` on the CC2020 french version.

I used this on CC2018 english and it worked :

```
var returned = app.findMenuCommandId('Save Animation Preset...');
app.executeCommand(returned);
```

then used the translated string on CC2020 french :

```
var returned = app.findMenuCommandId('Enregistrer l'animation prédéfinie...');
app.executeCommand(returned);
```

returned is 0 here so nothing happens.

The french string is exactly the same as read on the menu.
I'm using a Windows UTF-8 .jsx file.
Maybe there is a way to encode special characters with accent for the string to match ?

Any help would be very appreciated !

Comment: (stab in the dark) what happens if you run the script with the English menu item (`'Save Animation Preset...'`) on the French AE?

Comment: With English menu name on French AE, `app.findMenuCommandId` returns 0

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the number id? From a list i got, save animation preset should be 3075. So...
app.executeCommand(3075);

Here is where i found that list.

https://www.provideocoalition.com/wp-content/uploads/AECC2015_MenuIDs_v1_0_1-1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you would need to use double quotes, as the apostrophe will mess up your string. Try:

```
var returned = app.findMenuCommandId("Enregistrer l'animation prédéfinie...");
app.executeCommand(returned);
```

I am unable to test this on the French version, so hopefully it works.